# How to attach an SQL Server database containing File Stream from one server to another server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I inherited a database, there is no backup.

This database was created on SQL Server 2017 (v14) and the server is no longer available.

I have the `.MDF`, `.LDF` and the `filestream.hdr` files.

Now I want to attach this database to SQL Server 2017.

As you guess it, the attached process fails.

If I try to attached from Management Studio, I get an error that the file stream folder cannot be located.

However, if I point to the folder in script, I get File Activation Error.

There are two folders in the MyDB_Filestream folder but both are empty.
`$FSGC` and `$FSLOG`

What am I missing?

```
USE MASTER;
GO

 CREATE DATABASE [MyDB] ON 
 ( FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL14.InstanceName\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB.mdf' ),
 ( FILENAME = N'L:\MSSQL14.InstanceName\MSSQL\Log\MyDB_log.ldf' ),
    
 FILEGROUP [MyFileStream] CONTAINS FILESTREAM DEFAULT 
    
 ( NAME = N'MyFileStream', FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL14.InstanceName\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_FileStream' )
    
 FOR ATTACH
    
 GO
```

Comment: Do you have backups?

Comment: I think the correct syntax would be, `FOR ATTACH WITH FILESTREAM (DIRECTORY_NAME = N'MyFileStream')`

Comment: No backup, I even created the path which is missing and added the files there but still getting `File Activation Errors errors`. Not sure what is missing.

Comment: I found the answer here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/80623/how-to-reattach-sql-2008-database-without-filestream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on another post I did the following to resolved this issue:

Create a new database with the same name as the database I am attempting to attach. (The MDF and LDF names must match)

Take the database offline and terminate all connections.

Go to the folder where the new database is located and delete both the MDF and LDF files.

Copy the files of the database I am attempting to attach and put them into the exact folder where the new DB was located before they were deleted.

Make sure SQL Server has adequate access to the pasted DB file, MDF, LDF.

Now in SSMS bring the database back online.

I did the above and everything worked.

I immediately backed-up the databases.

Comment: Interesting approach. :) And did this also re-enable the FILESTREAM functionality of the database? (I have no experience with FILESTREAM, so I am just curious.)

Comment: Well honestly I did not check as I am not implementing file stream but it is indeed interesting giving 90% of the comments I found indicated the database was dead.

Comment: Simple way. I did try this but nor solve my problem. I steel get this error: A file activation error occurred. The physical file name 'C:\....\ProductImage' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation. this was the path of file stream.