# Attach a database with file stream

Tags: sql-server, filestream, database-restore

The point is next:
I had an sql server with database, then some smart people put a new computer with new sql server and removed previous machine. All that i have now is an hdd with DB.mdf and DB_log.ldf files, no backups, no access to old sql server. And i need restore the database to new server, but i had filestream enabled and when i trying to do this with MS studio interface context menu or "CREATE DATABASE ... FOR ATTACH" command i get an error like "Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\FileStreamFolder". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)"

Command that i used:

```
CREATE DATABASE NAME_DB
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\NAME_DB.mdf'),
(FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\NAME_DB_log.ldf'),
(FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\FileStreamFolder')
FOR ATTACH;
```

Notice that original filestream folder was on a different path and had a subfolder with a few folders inside and the file named filestream.hdr

I researched forum by this case, but other topics don't suit for me or they were asked a long time ago like 5-10 years.

Sorry for mistakes in speech, im not native. And thankyou for answers!

Comment: please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67480976/906453) , i test it and it works !

Answer (score -1):

Oh, sorry for worrying. The answer is a give a full access for all groups of users and etc. on the folder. I don't know if it is safe, but it works. Maybe it will help someone else.